# Marginal Density confusion.

Tags: probability

> Let $X$ and $Y$ be continuous random variables with joint density function $$f(x, y) = \begin{cases}15y & \mathrm{for}\,x^2\le y\le x \\ 0 & \mathrm{otherwise}\end{cases}$$ Let $g$ be the marginal density function of $Y$. Which of the following represents $g$?

Since $x \ge x^2$, obviously $x\in [0, 1]$. So for the marginal density of $y$, we integrate this joint pdf with respect to $\mathrm dx$ only from $0$ to $1$, to get $g = 15y$ for the interval $y$ is from $x^2$ to $x$, correct no? But they used the limits of integration for $x$ not from $0$ to $1$ but from $y$ to $\sqrt{y}$ to get this answer even manipulating the interval of $y$ now to $0$ to $1$: $$g(y) = \begin{cases}15y^{3/2}\left(1 - y^{1/2}\right)& \mathrm{for}\, 0 < y < 1 \\ 0 & \mathrm{otherwise}\end{cases}$$

Answer (score 1):

First of all the interval for $g(y)$ cannot be depend on $x$. It has to depend on $y$ only. Now let´s evaluate the limits of the integral. For this purpose we consider both 2 inequalities:

1. $x^2\leq y\ \Rightarrow \  -\sqrt y\leq x\leq \sqrt y$
2. $y\leq x$

The intersection of both solutions for $x$ is $y\leq x\leq \sqrt y$, since $y$ is always not negative.

Now we can integrate w.r.t $x$ to obtain the marginal distribution:

$$g(y)=\int_y^{\sqrt y } 15y \, dx$$

The range of $y$ is the solution of $y\leq \sqrt y$. This inequality can be solved by substitution $u=\sqrt y$. You will get a quadratic inequality.